# placeholder not working in django-cms

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I am using django cms to develop a site, configured everything and working fine,and below are my code files

**settings.py**

```
   ........
   ........

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
       'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
       'django.core.context_processors.request',
       'django.core.context_processors.media',
       'django.core.context_processors.static',
       'cms.context_processors.media',
       'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'terms_and_conditions': {
        'name': gettext('Terms & Conditions'),
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin'],
    },
}

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
       ('home.html', 'Home Page'),
)

........
.......
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<html>
<head> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to Services</title>
{% render_block "css" %}
</head>
<body>
{% cms_toolbar %}
    <div class="promoinner">
       {% block base_content %}{% endblock %} 
    </div>
  {% render_block "js" %}
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
   {% placeholder "terms_and_conditions" or  %}
       <p>This data should be present in the editor in editing mode before entering anything in to plugins, because this data is giving through html</p>
       <p>But when i tried to edit the placeholder i cant see the data(that we mentioned in tags of html file), i can able to see the placeholder and i can able to add some data in to text plugin </p>
   {% endplaceholder %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here all the problem is, we are giving some data through `p` tags in html file, so when i opened the url `http://localhost:8000/?edit`, i can able to see the placeholder named as 
`Terms & Conditions` as we mentioned in the settings.py file, but the data we given in html file through tags is not editable and cant be seen, at the same time i can able to add some text in to placeholder using `text` plugin.

Can anyone please let me know why the data that mentioned through html tags in `home.html` is not editable and even cant be seen ?

Answer (score 1):

try to load the placeholder tags in "base.html" or "home.html" like(looks like your missing "placeholder_tags")...

{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags placeholder_tags %}

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, actually i waiting eagerly for someone to reply for this question. yeah i had added the placeholder tag to base.html, but the same problem, when i added any placeholder i can able to add the data in to it by using plugins. It is fine, but when we are creating a site, we will design it with html right ? and by using placeholder we want to edit that entered data dynamically, so here i had given the data through html tags, but when i tried to edit that through placeholders it can't be seen actually.